# SQL Server: Sum up total value of local variable inside WHILE loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, for-loop, while-loop

May I know how to write a statement to sum up the total value from different `n` in a WHILE loop in SQL Server?

Following is my code:

```
Declare n int = 0
    WHILE (n<5)
        IF ( @fruit = 'Apple')
            SET @price = 2
        IF ( @fruit = 'Banana')
            SET @price = 3
    SET n = n+1
        END
```

How can I sum up all the price from `n = 0` to `n = 4?`

What I tried:

```
Declare n int = 0
SET @price = 0
WHILE (n<5)
        IF ( @fruit = 'Apple')
            SET @price = @price + 2
        IF ( @fruit = 'Banana')
            SET @price = @price + 3
    SET n = n+1
        END
```

But it only returns the price at last iteration `n=4`

Comment: What is the expected result? Why cant you just multiply `@price = 2 * 5`?

Comment: @KLyeo! from where value of `@fruit` is initializing?

Comment: I cannot determine the expected answer. I have used the example above so that my problem is easier to understand.

Comment: @Mohsin! The @fruit is passed in as a parameter in my stored procedure.

Comment: Do you have a particular reason for doing this computation inside a loop instead of using a conventional set based approach?

Answer (score 0):

Seems your query is right and it yield the right result as you can validate in below fiddle.

**[DB FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=157494d21dba20ef1e6ebfe4d03c4b6e)**

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @loop INT
DECLARE @price INT
SET @price = 0
SET @loop = 1

WHILE @loop <= 5
BEGIN
    IF (@fruit = 'Apple')
       SET @price = @price + 2
    IF (@fruit = 'Banana')
       SET @price = @price + 3
    SET @loop = @loop +1
END
```

Instead of loop, you can re write like below

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @Price INT = 0     
IF (@fruit = 'Apple')
BEGIN
     SET @price = 5 * 2
END
IF (@fruit = 'Banana')
BEGIN
     SET @price = 5 * 3
END
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I have done but it only returns the last price of the fruit

Comment: @KLyeo No, You will get sum reult and you can check here https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0830d58ed246b78109834df3b652baad

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Declare @n int = 0
Declare @fruit varchar(50)='apple'
declare @price int=0
   WHILE (@n<5)
   BEGIn
        IF ( @fruit = 'Apple')
            SET @price = @price + 2
        IF ( @fruit = 'Banana')
            SET @price = @price + 3
    SET @n = @n+1
    print @price
        END
```

Output:

```
2  
4  
6  
8  
10
```